# Cannot pass arguments in the invoke function I recreated

Tags: javascript, arguments, underscore.js

I am trying to recreate .invoke() function.

I am able to call the function, but struggling with passing the arguments. I tried using `call` and `apply`, but couldn't make it work.

Here is my code:

```
_.invoke = function (collection, methodName) {
  let newArr = [];

  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);

  if (collection instanceof Array) {
    for (let index = 0; index < collection.length; index++) {

      let keysArr = Object.keys(collection);
      let element = collection[keysArr[index]];

      newArr.push(element[methodName]());
    };

  } else if (collection instanceof Object) {
    for (let index = 0; index < Object.entries(collection).length; index++) {

      let keysArr = Object.keys(collection);
      let element = collection[keysArr[index]];

      newArr.push(element[methodName]());
    }
  }

  return newArr;
};
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both the array and the object case, you show a call that doesn't attempt to pass `args` to the method:

```js
newArr.push(element[methodName]());
```

Since `args` is an array, the easiest way to pass them is by using `apply`. `apply` takes two arguments. The first is whatever should be considered `this` inside the call to the method, which is `element` in this case. The second argument is the array of arguments that should be passed to the method. We end up with this form:

```js
newArr.push(element[methodName].apply(element, args));
```

Having answered the core of your question, let's see how else we could make your version of `invoke` better. First, we will take a look at the array case:

```js
    for (let index = 0; index < collection.length; index++) {

      let keysArr = Object.keys(collection);
      let element = collection[keysArr[index]];

      newArr.push(element[methodName].apply(element, args));
    };
```

The way in which you determine `element` here is a bit inefficient. You recompute `Object.keys(collection)` on every iteration, even though it never changes. Moreover, you do not actually need `keysArr`; `element` is just `collection[index]`. So we can change the array part into this:

```js
    for (let index = 0; index < collection.length; index++) {
      let element = collection[index];
      newArr.push(element[methodName].apply(element, args));
    };
```

We have a similar problem in the object part:

```js
    for (let index = 0; index < Object.entries(collection).length; index++) {

      let keysArr = Object.keys(collection);
      let element = collection[keysArr[index]];

      newArr.push(element[methodName].apply(element, args));
    }
```

Besides `Object.keys(collection)`, you are also recomputing `Object.entries(collection)` on every iteration, which *also* never changes. However, in this case, you do need `keysArr`. The solution is to compute it once *before* the loop and reuse it:

```js
    let keysArr = Object.keys(collection);
    for (let index = 0; index < keysArr.length; index++) {
      let element = collection[keysArr[index]];
      newArr.push(element[methodName].apply(element, args));
    }
```

At this point, we have an efficient implementation of `_.invoke` that works. However, since this is Underscore, let us also try whether we can introduce more functional style.

Functional style is all about how we can compose existing functions into new functions. In the specific case of `_.invoke`, we can see that it is essentially a special case of `_.map`. Since `_.map` already knows how to iterate over arrays as well as objects and it already returns a new array, just like `_.invoke`, this means that we can *reduce* our challenge. Instead of doing the "call a method with arguments" thing for the whole collection, we just need to figure out how to do it for a single element, and then compose that somehow with `_.map`.

Starting with just a function that does the job for a single element, we already know that it goes like this:

```js
function invokeElement(element, methodName, args) {
    return element[methodName].apply(element, args);
}
```

Now, this version of `invokeElement` is not quite ready to be passed to `_.map`. `_.map` will know which `element` to pass, but it knows nothing about `methodName` or `args`. Somehow, we need to pass `methodName` and `args` "ahead of time", so that `_.map` will be able to suffice just by passing `element`. `_.partial` lets us do exactly that:

```js
const partialInvoke = _.partial(invokeElement, _, methodName, args);
```

This line means: take `invokeElement` and create a new version of the function, where the second and third argument are already set to `methodName` and `args`, respectively, but the first argument still depends on what will be passed in the future. The underscore `_` used here as a placeholder is the very same underscore as in `_.map` and `_.partial`, i.e., the default export of the Underscore library.

Now, we have everything we need to compose `invoke` out of `_.map` and `invokeElement`:

```js
function invoke(collection, methodName) {
    const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
    const partialInvoke = _.partial(invokeElement, _, methodName, args);
    return _.map(collection, partialInvoke);
}
```

We can still do better. Using `_.restArguments`, we no longer need to compute `args`:

```js
const invoke = _.restArguments(function(collection, methodName, args) {
    const partialInvoke = _.partial(invokeElement, _, methodName, args);
    return _.map(collection, partialInvoke);
});
```

Alternatively, we can use modern spread syntax, which didn't exist yet when `_.restArguments` was invented:

```js
function invoke(collection, methodName, ...args) {
    const partialInvoke = _.partial(invokeElement, _, methodName, args);
    return _.map(collection, partialInvoke);
}
```

Regardless, we have our own implementation of `invoke` in just two lines of code. That's the power of functional style!